# Creación de un INDICE en base a condiciones - PYTHON

Tags: python

intento crear una variable que sea un índice que vaya aumentando de uno en uno el valor a medida que va corriendo cada dato del dataframe:

Lo que intenté de momento hacer es lo siguiente:

En primer lugar cree en mi dataframe una columna con todo el índice automático

> df['INDICE']= df.index

Ahora lo que necesito es que para determinadas condiciones, los números de ese indice sean los mismos y a medida que avanza, se repita esa convención, este es el código que intento aplicar para el caso.

Mi dataframe tiene las siguientes variables: Fecha, Concepto, Importe y ahora INDICE

Lo que necesito es lo siguiente, en caso de que la fecha y el concepto sean idénticos a lo largo de la tabla, el indice en ese caso sea el mismo. Es decir, si para el primer y segundo dato la fecha y el concepto son identicos, el valor del índice es 1. Si pasa lo mismo con el dato 3 y 4 el indice es 2 y así sucesivamente, en caso de que no coincidan, sigo incrementando en 1 mi valor del indice.

Lo que he intentado, pero no funciona es lo siguiente:

> for i in range(i, len(df)):
> if df.iloc[i, 'Concepto'] == df.iloc[i, 'Concepto'] and df.iloc[i, 'Fecha'] == df.iloc[i, 'Fecha']:
>
> ```
>     df['INDICE'] = df.index
>
> else: 
>     df['INDICE'] = df.index +1
> ```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `dataframes` en `pandas` no son mutables, por tanto, no puedes cambiar el valor de 'INDICES' en cada iteración, sin mencionar que no estás indexando la fila del `dataframe`.

Si lo que quieres es darle un índice único a cada fila, de manera que cada fila sea única y no existan filas repetidas la solución más elegante sería algo como:

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b' : 2},{'a': 1, 'b': 2},{'a': 100, 'b': 200},
          {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000},{'a': 1000, 'b': 2000}]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
df = df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index =True)
df['INDICE']= df.index
```

y obtendrás:

```
      a     b  INDICE
0     1     2       0
1   100   200       1
2  1000  2000       2
```

Si en cambio (como al parecer es tu objetivo), solo quieres rotular filas iguales y continuas con el mismo índice, una posible solución es crear primero una lista con los índices y luego asignarla al dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b' : 2},{'a': 1, 'b': 2},{'a': 100, 'b': 200},
          {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000},{'a': 1000, 'b': 2000}]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

indx = 0
indx_list = [0]
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['a'] == df.iloc[i-1] ['a'] and df.iloc[i-1] ['b'] == df.iloc[i] ['b']:
          indx_list.append(indx)
    else: 
        indx += 1
        indx_list.append(indx)
        
df['INDICE']= indx_list
```

Obteniendo:

```
      a     b  INDICE
0     1     2       0
1     1     2       0
2   100   200       1
3  1000  2000       2
4  1000  2000       2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime, es así tal cuál lo expresas en el resultado, voy a intentar aplicarlo a mi dataframe que ya tiene sus propios datos.

Comment: Jaime, funcionó perfecto! Gracias

Comment: Me alegra que te haya sido útil!!!!